# Display data from sql database into labels based on dropdown selection

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, label

I am new in .net. I have the following code and I know it is incorrect:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY FirstName", conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlUsers.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlUsers.DataTextField = "FirstName";
            ddlUsers.DataSource = rd;
            ddlUsers.DataBind();
            rd.Close();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [LastName], [Email], [Phone] FROM [Users] WHERE ([FirstName] = @FirstName)", conn);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", ddlUsers.SelectedItem.ToString());
            SqlDataReader rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd1.Read())
            {
                lblPhoneShow.Text = rd1["Phone"].ToString();
                lblEmailShow.Text = rd1["Email"].ToString();
                lblLNShow.Text = rd1["LastName"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        }
```

Binding data to dropdown works great, but when I choose certain name, labels show nothing.  Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be executing the query.

Try this:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select (Phone, LastName, Email) from users where FirstName = @FirstName", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", ddlUsers.SelectedValue.ToString());
rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

**UPDATE**

The dropdown lists's *value* is the ID. You're comparing the FirstName in the database to this value. A firstname will never match an ID.

- If you want to search by the ID, change the SQL.
- If you want to search by the Name, change the property to SelectedItem (which will be a DataRow). Then drill down to the name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i just changed my code but it is still not working.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Now it works. But I faced another problem. It shows only the information for the first person at the dropdown list. When I change the name, the information in labels is not changing. Could you look at the code?

Comment: I don't see any code to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event for the drop down list. That is where the code in your page load event needs to be called from. Ideally, you'll move the second half of your Page_Load code into a separate function, and call it from Page_Load only if PostBack is false, and also from the SelectedIndexChanged event handler for your drop down list.

Comment: Yes, thank you again for your help! That is what i have already done and it works fine.